# How to send Notification Using our on Server If we have registration id of different device?

Tags: android

I have the registration Id in my database of my Own server.Now is it possible to send notification to devices using their registration id provided by the GCM.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can send notifications to the devices basing on registration Id.
Check the following for its implementation .

http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/how-to-send-push-notifications-using-gcm-service/